# How to center the images in the Owl Carousel

Tags: html, css, carousel, centering, owl-carousel

My Owl Carousel contains pictures of different width and height. How do I align them in the middle - both horizontally and vertically?

```js
$("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
  navigation: true
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css">

<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel">
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x120/69c/fff/" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/c69/fff/" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x160/9c6/fff/" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/240x240/fc6/fff/" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x160/9c6/fff/" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/c69/fff/" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x120/69c/fff/" alt=""></div>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1. The Owl Carousel creates additional blocks within your layout. To add CSS properties correctly, you need to work with this HTML structure:

   ```html
   <div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel owl-theme">
     <div class="owl-wrapper-outer">
       <div class="owl-wrapper">
         <div class="owl-item">
           <div>
             <img src="" alt="">
           </div>
         </div>
         <div class="owl-item">
           <div>
             <img src="" alt="">
           </div>
         </div>
       </div>
     </div>
   </div>
   ```
2. Moreover the carousel adds a `style` attribute to all blocks. For example, a block with the `.owl-wrapper` class receives the `display` property with the value of `block`. So you have to use an `!important` declaration in your CSS.
3. To obtain a horizontal alignment, you can simply add `text-align: center;` property to each `.owl-item > div`.
4. To align vertically, you can turn the carousel items in table cells. But do not forget to cancel the `float` property for them.

[image: screenshot]

Let us arrange all of the changes as a new `.owl-centered` class. Please check the result:

Owl Carousel 2.3.4: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/vYKMgzj
Owl Carousel 1.3.3: https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/BzgZxX

```js
$("#owl-example").owlCarousel({
  navigation: true
});
```

```css
@import url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.css');
@import url('//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.theme.min.css');

.owl-centered .owl-wrapper {
  display: table !important;
}
.owl-centered .owl-item {
  display: table-cell;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
.owl-centered .owl-item > div {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="owl-example" class="owl-carousel owl-centered">
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x120/69c/fff/" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/c69/fff/" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x160/9c6/fff/" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/240x240/fc6/fff/" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/160x160/9c6/fff/" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/200x200/c69/fff/" alt=""></div>
  <div><img src="https://via.placeholder.com/120x120/69c/fff/" alt=""></div>
</div>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/owl-carousel/1.3.3/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 56):

With owl carousel version 2.1.1 and CSS3 Flexbox, just add the style:

```
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

See the snippet:

```js
$( document ).ready( function() {
  $( '.owl-carousel' ).owlCarousel({
     autoplay: true,
     margin: 2,
     loop: true,
     responsive: {
        0: {
           items:1
        },
        200: {
           items:3
        },
        500: {
           items:4
        }
     }
  });
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.owl-carousel .caption {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/assets/owl.carousel.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/350x200/?text=1">
      <div class="caption">Caption 1</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/255x200/?text=2">
      <div class="caption">Caption 2</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/627x200/?text=3">
      <div class="caption">Caption 3</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/627x300/?text=4">
      <div class="caption">Caption 4</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/627x400/?text=5">
      <div class="caption">Caption 5</div>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
      <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/255x200/?text=6">
      <div class="caption">Caption 6</div>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/OwlCarousel2/2.2.1/owl.carousel.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: For some reason the solutions here weren't jiving with my layout, but I ended up getting it to work ok by setting a percentage value on the left margin of my divs that were turned to the item divs. But nice approach and thanks! This will likely work for me in the future.

Comment: I'm using Gantry 5 Helium on Grav and adding `display: flex` to `.owl-carousel .owl-stage` makes a line of the next image show on the right side of the current image, however, it's the only solution I've found that actually vertically centres all the images. Any ideas on how to get rid of the line? If anyone's willing to help I'll send you the URL.

Answer (score 5):

This works for me:

```
@media (max-width:500px) {
    .owl-carousel .owl-item {
        text-align:center;
    }
    .owl-carousel .item {
        float: none;
        display: inline-block;
    }
}
```

You might adjust it to your HTML though, but the idea is that you text-align a parent, and float:none and display:inline-block the child that holds the content, on mobile:

Comment: Thanks for the answer! But what about vertical centering? And the solution for a wide screen is of interest....

Answer (score 4):

The solution with display table is OK, but for me the divs on the right and left side slides out from the container. My code is close the same, I changed the `table` and `table-cell` to `block` and `inline-block`

```
.owl-stage{
  display: block !important;
}

.owl-item{
  display: inline-block;
  float: none;
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.item{
  text-align: center;
}
```

The result (all images has different sizes):
[image]

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to use flexbox with margin.

```css
.owl-stage-outer {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.owl-stage-outer > .owl-stage {
  margin:0 auto;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I advise this solution:

```
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
    margin: 0 auto; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but what about vertical centering?