# Owl Carousel align each item vertically when their height not equal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, owl-carousel

I'm working on a really simple Html/Bootstrap website.
I'm using `owl-carousel` library to display and slide multiple paragraphs.
The problem is that when displaying on small devices, these paragraphs will not have the same height, depending on how long they are.

I would like all my `owl-item` div or paragraph to be aligned vertically within the owl-wrapper div. I tried few display combinations, and also the owl carousel's `autoHeight: true` option but it does not work as I except.

See the pictures, the little paragraph is displayed on the top of the owl-wrapper div, but I would like it to be centered vertically:

[image]

[image]

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="caption text-center text-white" data-stellar-ratio="0.7">
        <div id="owl-intro-text" class="owl-carousel">
            <div class="item">
                <h1>Oscar Götting</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="item">
                <h1>Let's build something together</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to center the images in the Owl Carousel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39164738/how-to-center-the-images-in-the-owl-carousel)

Answer (score 16):

Add this to your CSS

```
.owl-carousel .owl-stage { display: flex; align-items: center; }
```