# Centered owl-carousel where each image has the same hight and keeps its aspect ratio

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, owl-carousel

Is there an approach to to create a centered [owl-carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/) where each image has the same height without losing its aspect ratio?

I tried to calculate the image sizes with JS/jQuery, but then the calculation of the `owl-carousel` gets messed up. Same result with CSS s. example ([JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/wittich/we20vhtz/)):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.loop').owlCarousel({
        center: true,
        items: 3,
        loop: true,
        margin: 20
    });
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
  height: 150px;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  height: 100%;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item .item {
  height: 100%;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
  height: 100% !important;
  width: auto !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
<div class="loop owl-carousel owl-theme">
    <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x460/ff0000/000000?text=IMG 01" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/460x320/00ffff/000000?text=IMG 02" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x80/00ff00/000000?text=IMG 03" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x100/ff00ff/000000?text=IMG 04" /></div>
    <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/70x80/ffff00/000000?text=IMG 05" /></div>
</div>
```

The current `div`/`image` should be

- in the center of the carousel,
- has the same height like all other items
- keeps it aspect ratio and
- is side by side to the previous or next item.

*If the element is bigger wider then the viewport, well than it gets cut.*

Is there even a method to achieve that with the [owl-carousel](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/)?

---

I checked some other similar questions on SO but as far I can see they have all different focus:

- [Image slider: maintaining equal height for all images while keeping slider responsive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21574698/)

  ```js
   // overrides the aspect ratio
  ```
- [Owl Carousel align each item vertically when their height not equal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39320305/)

  ```js
   // not the same height of each item*
  ```

---

I just double checked the [auto-height demo](https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/demos/autoheight.html)...

> To enable use `autoHeight: true`. At the moment works only with 1 item on screen. The plan is to calculate all visible items and change height according to highest item.

Seems like there is not such an options yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all of your images have the same height - try adding autoWidth: true:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('.owl-carousel').owlCarousel({
      center: true,
      margin:10,
      loop:true,
      autoWidth:true,
      items:4
  })
});
```

```css
.owl-carousel .owl-stage {
  height: 200px;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item {
  height: 100%;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item .item {
  height: 100%;
}

.owl-carousel .owl-item img {
  height: 100% !important;
  width: auto !important;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.carousel.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/assets/owl.theme.default.min.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/vendors/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://owlcarousel2.github.io/OwlCarousel2/assets/owlcarousel/owl.carousel.js"></script>
    <div class="loop owl-carousel owl-theme">
        <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x460/ff0000/000000?text=IMG 01" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/460x320/00ffff/000000?text=IMG 02" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/100x80/00ff00/000000?text=IMG 03" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/50x100/ff00ff/000000?text=IMG 04" /></div>
        <div class="item"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/70x80/ffff00/000000?text=IMG 05" /></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Thanks, this works for me. The crucial part is to use the `!important` flag for the image width otherwise it gets overwritten by OwlCarousel's CSS and the images lose their aspect ratio.